# Vue.js Select Options In Form Not Rendering Immediately in Component Using Pinia Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So i have a form component

```
<template>
  <div class="flex h-screen w-screen items-center justify-center">
    <div
      name="form container"
      class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn mx-auto flex h-fit w-[70%] flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-300 shadow-xl"
    >
      <div name="question" class="flex w-[80%] flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3 p-3">
        <p class="text-2xl font-semibold">Question</p>
        <textarea
          autofocus
          class="w-[80%]"
          placeholder="Add a question"
          v-model="question"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div name="border" class="mx-auto w-[50%] rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-400"></div>
      <div name="answers" class="flex w-[80%] flex-col gap-2 p-3">
        <FormAnswer
          ansPlaceholder="Answer A"
          v-model:modelValue="answers[0]"
          :class="{
            'font-bold text-green-500': correctAnswer === 'Answer A'
          }"
        ></FormAnswer>
        <FormAnswer
          ansPlaceholder="Answer B"
          v-model:modelValue="answers[1]"
          :class="{
            'font-bold text-green-500': correctAnswer === 'Answer B'
          }"
        ></FormAnswer>
        <FormAnswer
          ansPlaceholder="Answer C"
          v-model:modelValue="answers[2]"
          :class="{
            'font-bold text-green-500': correctAnswer === 'Answer C'
          }"
        ></FormAnswer>
        <FormAnswer
          ansPlaceholder="Answer D"
          v-model:modelValue="answers[3]"
          :class="{
            'font-bold text-green-500': correctAnswer === 'Answer D'
          }"
        ></FormAnswer>
        <FormAnswer
          ansPlaceholder="Answer E"
          v-model:modelValue="answers[4]"
          :class="{
            'font-bold text-green-500': correctAnswer === 'Answer E'
          }"
        ></FormAnswer>

        <p>Select correct answer</p>
        <select v-model="correctAnswer">
          <option value="Answer A">Answer A</option>
          <option value="Answer B">Answer B</option>
          <option value="Answer C">Answer C</option>
          <option value="Answer D">Answer D</option>
          <option value="Answer E">Answer E</option>
        </select>
        <p>Select a dataset</p>
        <select>
          <option v-for="db in databaseOptions" :key="db.name" :value="db">{{ db }}</option>
        </select>

        <button
          class="mx-auto mt-2 w-fit rounded-3xl border-2 border-black p-3 text-xl font-semibold transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105 hover:bg-black hover:text-white"
          @click="getFormData()"
        >
          Submit question
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import 'animate.css'
//components impor
import FormAnswer from '../AdminDashboardCmp/FormAnswer.vue'
// import from vue and axios
import { ref, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue'
// import stores
import { useAdminDashboardStore } from '../../stores/UIStore/adminDashboardStore'
import { useGlobalStore } from '../../stores/globalStore'
// stores
const adminStore = useAdminDashboardStore()
const globalStore = useGlobalStore()
//
const question = ref('')
const answers = []
const databaseOptions = reactive(globalStore.databaseOptions)
const correctAnswer = ref('')
const correctAnswerText = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(`the component is now mounted.`)
  globalStore.listName()
})

function getFormData() {
  updateCorrectAnswerText()
  // getCollectionsNames()
  globalStore.hello()

  //

  const questionFull = {
    title: question.value,
    answers: answers,
    correctAnswer: correctAnswerText.value
  }
}
function updateCorrectAnswerText() {
  // Znajdź odpowiednią treść odpowiedzi na podstawie wybranej opcji
  switch (correctAnswer.value) {
    case 'Answer A':
      correctAnswerText.value = answers[0]
      break
    case 'Answer B':
      correctAnswerText.value = answers[1]
      break
    case 'Answer C':
      correctAnswerText.value = answers[2]
      break
    case 'Answer D':
      correctAnswerText.value = answers[3]
      break
    case 'Answer E':
      correctAnswerText.value = answers[4]
      break
    default:
      correctAnswerText.value = ''
      break
  }
}
</script>
```

And the problem is that the Options in Select, that comes from pinia store, redner after i make any intervention in form. For example, the component is rendered, and select options are empty. I wait sometime. I write a letter in form and then the options in form appear. If i render again, and immediately i put a key stroke in from, the options in select appears. How to render options in select with the component.

Comment: Did you try using `ref` instead of `reactive`?

Comment: yes, didnt help :( thanks for idea sir!

Comment: Perhaps you've done something wrong in the store?

Comment: Can you please add your store file as well? Is the options coming from any APIs or is it static in store?